# When a Spherical variety is $K$-stable

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, k-stability

Let $X=G/H$ for a reductive group $G$ and $X$ is normal and has an open $B$-orbit, for a Borel subgroup $B$ then we call $X$ spherical.

> My question is When a Spherical variety is [$K$-stable](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4669v2.pdf)?  Is there
>   any algebraic equivalence for K-stability of a Spherical variety?

Comment: K-stability depends on the choice of a polarization. What polarization do you want to choose?

Comment: How do you define K-stability for manifolds which are not projective?

Comment: In affine case we have T-equivariant test configuration and we can define Futaki-Donaldson invariant. You can see papers in Sasakian setting and k-stability. Also I assumed here polarization is $L=K_X^{-1}$ . See http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3686